# using shared memory with php and python?

Tags: php, memory, shared

Can you use shared memory to communicate between php scripts and python program in windows,PHP is running as a web server module ?

i've used this in my php script : :

```
$shm_id = shmop_open($id, "c", 0644, strlen($data));
$shm_size = shmop_size($shm_id);
$shm_bytes_written = shmop_write($shm_id,$data, 0);
exec("c:/python27/python script.py",$output);
if(sizeof($output)){
   //operations....
}
shmop_delete($shm_id)
shmop_close($shm_id);
```

can i retrieve $data  from in python ? 
any references ?

Comment: No, because you've deleted it.

Comment: He deleted it after executing the python script.

Comment: oops ! my bad but i have these lines commented out in my text editor !
so how i can do that on python ! thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it as an argument to your python script using subprocess.call instead of exec it looks like this:

```
returnCode = subprocess.call(['path/script.py', arg1, arg2])
```

You can find the docs at: http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

From python get the args with:

`args[0]` is the program name from the command line

`args[1]` is arg1

`args[2]` is arg2

etc.